How Do I Disable PowerBI "Count Of" En Masse and Disable Summarization
I need help changing default summarization and renaming table fields en masse. All of the answers on this that I have found online seem outdated. Please someone help me
Hello, I am using powerBI to make charts from a large set of data. My problem is that when I drag one of the data fields (columns) to the X-axis it utilizes the "Count Of" summarization by default and I need it to actually use "Sum Of" or "Average Of" or whatever will show the true datapoint. Its only one record so I know that those two work to do that.
I am aware this exists
I also am aware that you can double click the X-Axis button in order to manually change it to what I want it to be, HOWEVER I am working to create well over 200 charts and that would be a very tedious task. I did see online that under the Model tab in powerBI there was an option to change the default summarization however that is not the case for me so I am assuming that it was discontinued.
I have seen this
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/345732iD19B7824F280D9FD/image-dimensions/2500?v=v2&px=-1
However my PowerBi Looks like this:
My Power BI
On top of that, when I do leverage the Sum Of {X} / Count of {X} that is what is displayed in the X-Axis legend so I would also need to tediously remove that from the name of the aggregation too.
How Can I change this en masse?
My Axis Legend
So TLDR;
Is there a way to change the default summarization to simply use the values within the column instead of a summarization?
Is there a way to change the name of the aggregation of the values to not have "sum of" or "average of" at the start. I need to do this en masse for 200-400 charts so just clicking and manually changing it wont do.

you can try to select the column and in the column tools , set the Summarization to sum. Then it will be sum of automatically when you add this column to y-axis.


Hey, how did you get that option to select the summarization? I do not have it or any column tools for that matter.

I found it. Is there any way to have that option but for all of the columns in the table at once?

we have to set it one by one. You can select the column , then you will see the column tools tab.
